# File Sync Framework: Sync system files between a local computer and a remote computer not on the same network

Tags: file-io, remote-server, microsoft-sync-framework

Can someone provide an example (or a link to one) illustrating how to sync system files (not database) between a local computer and a remote computer/server not on the same network?

Syncing files within the same pc and syncing files between pc's within the same network is straightforward and rather simple. I have those scenarios working nicely.

I need to sync files from "C:\FilesToSync" to a remote endpoint or an IP address. a WCF, HTTP,  FTP, or TCP implementation is fine. Just need to learn how the sync needs to be set-up for any of those.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this is a really good question. for 'remote' front-end developers / designers like me lol, kinda hard to choose a nicely recommended solution; in some places it's git (OS independent), in certain .NET projects, it's TortoiseSVN-VisualStudio; when i search online, tons and tons of dunno-what-to-choose like BitBucket, GitHub's Fork.

I also am looking for the right 'generic' soln for months now...
Example:
1. working on a soln on one pc, large heavy files, the xml and psd types for instance
2. uploading/synchronising with my remote hosting server for clients
3. backup server on another location, comparing/collaborating/synchronising

some ppl might say 'u know, different projects require different solns, don't cum up with that cr*p please, thanks;

in the end, I use Notepad++ for remote files and my localhost, and Google Drive only for small doc files; meanwhile, winning combo dinosaur-style soln for the laymen in this field ;) ... 
usb and last'modified'date on MyComputer !

duh